# using chartjs in ionic framework with firebase

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, firebase, chart.js

I'm new at ionic framework.I want to use chartjs in my application based on data stored in firebase. here is my code which I retrieve data in list:

```
           <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items |reverse |limitTo:3">
              <b>  {{item.bg}}</b>
              <p> {{item.time}}</p>
              <p>  {{item.dayOfWeek}}</p
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

and have a canvas to show the data in chart:

also in my controller I have:

```
.factory("Items", function ($firebaseArray) {
var itemsRef = new Firebase("https://[my-firebase-    app].firebaseio.com/items");
return $firebaseArray(itemsRef);
```

})

```
.controller("ListCtrl", function ($scope, Items) {


$scope.items = Items;


    $scope.addItem = function () {

    $scope.items.$add({

      "bg": $scope.newBG,
      "dayOfWeek":dw,
      "date":dd,
      "time":hh 

    })
  }



};
```

the chart only work with static array data in controller, like this:

```
 $scope.graph = {};   
  $scope.graph.data =
 [
     [16, 15, 20, 12, 16, 12, 8],

    [8, 9, 4, 12, 8, 12, 14]
    ];
```

but I want to use dynamic data from firebase and when a data add in it, it shows in chart.
How Can I use that data and bind them to my chart where they are n Json format?
Is it right to use it like
 $scope.graph.data=Items.bg;

but it doesn't work.
Thank you for helping me

Comment: Are you able to post an example of the data to see how it looks?

Comment: for example they are like these data:    bg:150,     dayOfTheWeek:1 , date:15/3/2016 , time:12:30              ///////  I want to chart 'bg' data  based on date.

Comment: Assuming you have a collection of the data as per your comment, create 2 arrays, one for BG and one for the date, then once you have those arrays,  do `$scope.graph.data.push(bgArray)` and `$scope.graph.data.push(dateArray)`. Without seeing the exact data that's all I can suggest, let me know? Make a plunkr to demonstrate if you want more assistance :)

Comment: My sample data are these:{
  "items" : {
    "-KHzm0OahdwDmkMZZX9L" : {
      "bg" : "122",
      "date" : "2016/4/17",
      "time" : "22:3"
    },
    "-KHzm67JOssvap_HH_IV" : {
      "bg" : "160",
      "date" : "2016/4/17",
      "time" : "22:3"
    },
    "-KHzm773pznL-QdqV2fu" : {
      "bg" : "100",
      "date" : "2016/4/17",
      "time" : "22:3"
    }
  }
}